# How to protect Ubuntu12.10 from Viruses, Spywares, Spamware and Intruders?

Tags: java, security, apache2, firewall

I have been using Windows OS for a long time and there i needed to install a separate Anti virus Program (included with firewall, anti spam) etc..

With my mentor's recommendation, I have replaced Windows with Ubuntu12.10 64 bit. I really enjoyed the system. Its better than Windows OS.

I am a Java Developer, so I need to have Apache tomcat, JBoss and Glassfish installed along with MySQL.
For my job requirement, I need to google for above Java Develoment and end up getting into many blogs.

I have searched for protecting Ubuntu, but they all end up with configuring the firewall.
I really have no knowledge about how firewall needs to be configured according to my requirements. Do I also need to have an antivirus program on Ubuntu.

Can anybody guide me about how can I secure the Ubuntu 12.10 64bit System.

Your advice matters to me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is more about adware and malware than a virus, and **blocking such sites could be the solution you require**.

You can try using a utility like [**hostsblock**](http://gaenserich.github.com/hostsblock/) to prevent all connection between your computer and such sites. There is a **deb** file that can be downloaded as well. If the blocklists are not blocking those sites you complain about, you can also add them manually to the list. It also includes a script (`hostsblock-urlcheck.sh`) to identify the URL addresses involved so that you can add them easily to the block list.

Answer (score 1):

As there are very few viruses for Linux (and most of them are for experimental purposes), you shouldn't worry about a virus infecting your system. However, if you are also working with Windows (or with Windows users), it may be useful to scan your system for any file containing viruses, as you may infect the Windows machine when exchanging files.

For a list of Anti-Virus software for Linux, check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus) page.
Also, you can [visit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Linuxvirus) this page for getting more info about viruses in Linux.

Have a great day,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

olha amigo, ate onde eu sei ainda não foi desenvolvido nenhum tipo de vírus ou spyware que seja capas de afetar sistemas operacionais com kernel linux, que é o caso do ubuntu! 
Então no meu ponto de vista você pode ficar tranquilo,por que seu ubuntu esta seguro!
sem antivírus algum!!!

---

```
                                          English
```

Friend looks, as far as I know has not been developed any kind of virus or spyware that is covers affect operating systems with Linux kernel, which is the case of ubuntu! So in my view you can rest assured that your ubuntu is safe! without any antivirus!!

Answer (score 0):

There are so many types of threats to computers out there that I had to coin the phrase "Decontamination software" as a generic term to cover it all, as a former US Army NBC NCO, and airborne nurse the handle fits for me. This is what it seems you're referring to by securing your computer. The 64-bit computer in the house is a gaming computer and will retain Windows 7 for that reason, the 32 bit computer that I found with an uninstalled Windows XP operating system is up and running and has clam-tk installed, I later installed winclam on the 64-bit computer to work with spybot S&D, and defender, neither of which will work with LINUX systems, support options available from COMMODO, AVG, and AVAST were weak at best. I did see an evaluation of "Antivirus" software for LINUX on YOUTUBE, but can't find the link. I'm looking for the same thing for the LINUX mini-tower, so if I find anything more, it will be posted here for review. LEIGH BARTON